# Django ORM: get the monthly average of price for each category

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Imagine this simple model:

```
class Expense(models.Model):
   price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   category = models.CharField(choices=ExpenseCategory.choices, max_length=20)
   created_at = models.DateField()
```

I'm trying to get the monthly average of `price` for each `category` in the current year. My general thought was to do something like:

```
sub = (
   Expense.objects.filter(created_at__year=date.today().year)
   .annotate(month=TruncMonth("created_at"))
   .values("month", "category")
   .annotate(total=Sum("price"))
   .order_by("month")
)
qs = Expense.objects.values("category").annotate(avg=Avg(Subquery(sub.values("total"))))
```

I'm basically trying to:

1. Truncate the months of `created_at`
2. Group by `category` and `month`
3. Sum the `prices`
4. Aggregate the `prices` for each `category`

It works just fine if I do like:

```
for category in categories:
   sub.filter(category=category).aggregate(avg=Avg("total"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query can be more simple than you think. Your current attempt at the solution is:

1. Truncate `created_at` to get the month
2. Group by `category` and `month`
3. Sum `prices`
4. Take Avg of the sum for each category

The problem with this is taking an aggregate of an aggregate. Let's think of your problem in reverse (We will do a bit of mathematics here). You want the average of the monthly price of a category, if we consider only one category and the monthly prices to be an array `M[12]`, then we can express this as:

```
(M[0] + M[1] + ... + M[11]) / 12
```

Each of the values in M can be considered to be a summation of `prices` where the month matches. If we consider P[12][] to be a 2 dimensional array containing prices for each month we can rewrite above formula as:

```
(Sum(P[0]) + Sum(P[1] + ... + Sum(P[12])) / 12
```

Thinking of this further it is simply the sum of all prices in the year divided by 12! That means your query can simply be written as:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, FloatField, Sum, Value


qs = Expense.objects.filter(
    created_at__year=date.today().year
).values("category").annotate(
    avg=ExpressionWrapper(
        Sum("price") / Value(12), output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```

**Note**: Dividing by 12 means we are assuming that we have data for the entire year, this would probably not be true for the current year so instead we should divide by the appropriate number of months. We might also want to filter upto the previous month in case we are not significantly into the current month.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. The only thing I had to change was `Value (12)` to `Count("created_at__month", distinct=True)` because is not guaranteed that a user started using the system at least 12 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

A function within a model manager could be a good solution to this. In your `models.py` add a [models.Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) class called `ExpenseManager` before your `Expense` class:

```python
class ExpenseManager(models.Manager):
  def summarise_categories(self):
    return (
      super(ExpenseManager, self)
      .get_queryset()
      .filter(created_at__year=date.today().year)
      .annotate(month=TruncMonth("created_at"))
      .values("month", "category")
      .annotate(total=Sum("price")/Count("created_at__month", distinct=True))
   )
```

then in you `Expense` class do:

```python
class Expense(models.Model):
  ...
  
  objects = ExpenseManager()
```

To get the resulting queryset aggregation you can simply call the model manager method on the model objects within a view:

```
summarised_categories = Expense.objects.summarise_categories()
```

This approach pushes all the work to the database returning a dictionary of categories and their average monthly prices for the year-to-date.

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: Sorry about that @MuriloSitonio. I've made some edits to the model manager class - I forgot to include self in the summarise_cateogories method and I modified the annotation code to match what you found helpful from Abdul's answer. I've just recently found these manager based methods helpful for these kids of standard but slightly more complex queries which might be used in multiple places across the site - there's just one place to edit them if you need to.